# Feature Attribute Count Script

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes, count

Using an arcpy script how do I get the feature attribute count per feature class in a fileGDB? Ideally I would like to output to a spreadsheet, with the feature class name in one column and the attribute count in another.

Comment: by "feature attribute count" do you mean a count of how many features there are, or a count of how many attributes (fields?) a feature has?

Comment: The number of attributes per feature class in a fileGDB.

Answer (score 4):

Use this function to return all of the feature classes in the GDB:

```
def listFcsInGDB():
    for fds in arcpy.ListDatasets('','feature') + ['']:
        for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('','',fds):
            yield os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, fds, fc)
```

Now loop over that function to work with each individual feature class:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\gdb"
for fc in listFcsInGDB():
    print fc
    print arcpy.GetCount_management(fc) <-- number of rows
    print len(arcpy.ListFields(fc)) <-- number of columns
```

I've left the part about writing to a spreadsheet up to you.

Note, I haven't tested this so feel free to correct me if I made any mistakes.

Comment: I would use arcpy.da.walk() instead of arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()  http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000023000000